# Neo4j Cypher: topological sort in addition to regular sort?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Say I have a tree of nodes that looks like this:

[image]

Where **the numbers correspond to some value I *generally* want to sort by**. (It could be time, it could be some kind of score, whatever.)

If I return them sorted by just that number, I'd of course get this sort:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

That's generally fine, but in addition to this sort, I want to apply the constraint that **parents always sort before their children**. So what I really want is this sort:

```
3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

You can see this looks almost the same; we've just flipped the order of `1, 2, 3` to `3, 2, 1`.

**Is there a way to achieve this sort with a Neo4j Cypher query?**

—

Here's a live console example with this tree to play with:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/l9mav2

Here's my query so far:

```
MATCH path=( ({i: 3}) <-[:parent*0..]- (node) )
RETURN node, node.i, LENGTH(path)
```

I'm just not sure how to use this info:

- If I `ORDER BY node.i`, I get the first sort.
- If I `ORDER BY LENGTH(path)`, it's too aggressive. E.g. `9` before `5, 6, 7, 8`.
- Combining the two, in either order, doesn't work either.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels a little hacky, but maybe it will work, depending on how predictable the size of your tree is:

```
MATCH path=(root:Node { i: 3 })<-[:parent*0..]-(node:Node)
WITH nodes(path)[-1] as n,[x IN nodes(path)| x.i] AS o
ORDER BY o[0], coalesce(o[1], -1), coalesce(o[2], -1), coalesce(o[3], -1) // and so forth
RETURN n
```

Where the -1 in the coalesce is definitely lower than any possible values in the `.i` property.

Here's another idea using the properties of string comparison to our advantage:

```
MATCH path=(root:Node { i: 3 })<-[:parent*0..]-(node:Node)
WITH nodes(path)[-1] AS n,[x IN nodes(path)| x.i] AS o, 
     reduce(maxLen=0, p IN root<-[:parent*]-()|CASE WHEN maxLen < length(p)
                                                   THEN length(p)
                                                   ELSE maxLen END ) AS maxLen
ORDER BY reduce(acc='', x IN range(0,maxLen)|acc+coalesce(str(o[x]), ''))
RETURN n,reduce(acc='', x IN range(0,maxLen)|acc+coalesce(str(o[x]), ''))
```

You can either get the max path length as shown, or just make maxLen a really high number.

Comment: Does the number of `coalesce`s need to be the height of the tree? If so, no, we can't predict the height in advance. But I suppose I could prepend a query to derive the height first, then `WITH` it?

Comment: if you have too many it's ok, you just need to make the number of coalesces the max height. you just wouldn't want to do this for a really deep tree, or the query would be really ugly.

Comment: This is staggering btw — this is effectively a breadth-first ORDER BY. You truly are a Cypher God! =) Demo link that helped me see this in action: http://console.neo4j.org/r/diygsj

Comment: Well, we can't predict the max height either, so we'd hardcode something, e.g. 100, and hope we don't exceed that. That's pretty brittle though. Is there any way to adapt to dynamic heights?

Comment: A Cypher god probably would have written a breadth-first matcher with expressions to order by instead of hacking together a crazy long order by in a query. :P

Comment: I'll think about it some more.

Comment: Your new answer is GENIUS! It's actually even particularly suited for us, because in practice, our `i` is already a string. (ISO 8601 timestamp.) Thank you! =)

Comment: It occurred to me that you can just use `node` instead of the `nodes(path)[-1]`, at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You can just combine the two values to represent your sort order, just giving the parents a higher precendence:

```
MATCH path =((root:Node { i: 3 })<-[:parent*0..]-(node:Node))
RETURN node, node.i, LENGTH(path)
ORDER BY LENGTH(path)+ node.id *10
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/ijeqlv

returns

```
+--------------------------------------+
| node         | node.i | LENGTH(path) |
+--------------------------------------+
| Node[3]{i:3} | 3      | 0            |
| Node[2]{i:2} | 2      | 1            |
| Node[1]{i:1} | 1      | 2            |
| Node[4]{i:4} | 4      | 1            |
| Node[5]{i:5} | 5      | 2            |
| Node[6]{i:6} | 6      | 2            |
| Node[7]{i:7} | 7      | 2            |
| Node[8]{i:8} | 8      | 3            |
| Node[9]{i:9} | 9      | 1            |
+--------------------------------------+
9 rows
32 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Michael, but I don't think that's right. The property is `i`, not `id`; when I fix your query to use that, the sort is different.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that `LENGTH(path)` in isolation isn't really what I care about — it's the parent-child relationships between nodes that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Neo4j, but if I understand correctly, the following algorithm, in words, fits your description. Best of luck!

Start at the root node and copy the root into the sorted list as your next value. Choosing among the root's children, choose the "next root" as the smallest of the root's children. Replace the root by the "next root", and move all of the "next root's" children up a level. Repeat until the graph is empty.

Ex:

```
Sorted = {}
           3
        /  |  \
       2   4   9
       |  /|\
       1 5 6 7
             |
             8
Sorted = {3}
       2
     / | \
    1  4  9
      /|\
     5 6 7
         |
         8
Sorted = {3,2}
       1
       | \
       4  9
      /|\
     5 6 7
         |
         8
Sorted = {3,2,1}
         4  
      / / \  \
     5 6   7  9
           |
           8
Sorted = {3,2,1,4}
          5  
        / | \
       6  7  9
          |
          8
Sorted = {3,2,1,4,5}
         6  
        /  \
       7    9
       |
       8
Sorted = {3,2,1,4,5,6}
         7  
        /  \
       8    9
Sorted = {3,2,1,4,5,6,7}
          8  
          |
          9
Sorted = {3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8}
          9
Sorted = {3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

Comment: The OP wasn't asking for an algorithm. Basically you illustrated what he's already requesting in a Cypher query.

Comment: Thanks folks. I agree I'm aware of general algorithms, but it's not unhelpful to see one spelled out here. =) Maybe if we deem it's not possible in Cypher, we could implement this in Gremlin.